# LUA FFI : attempt to redefine error when doing multiple ffi.cdef

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

Let me make it simple.

I have multiple tests to run and after each test I do clear all the requires made by the current test using package.loaded[] = nil.

The problem is though we remove the required files from global namespace , I see that the ffi.cdef done by those files remain intact and when I do require agian, It throws an error as "attempt to redefine ''"

Do we have any method by which  we can clear the cdef loaded? or can retrieve the cdef loaded, so that I can save the old cdef and restore back once the test is done? Or is there anyother method I can do the same task?

I am just looking for something like ffi.uncdef.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function, and for good reason.

First of all, setting `package.loaded[pkg] = nil` is *not* an official way to unload a module, especially C code. [See one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110042/646619). Additionally, unloading cdefs is not that simple; what happens if you unload a cdef that has objects using it?

The only way to test code that runs cdefs is by creating a new `lua_State` or luajit process for each test.

(Also, it's [Lua, not LUA](http://luanotlua.com/))

Comment: Yes I do create a seperate env for each test but as the test script share the same require and ffi module, they do corrupt the whole Global namespace. I did a workaround for the require by removing all the modules loaded by the test but not finding anyway for the cdefs.

Comment: Environments are not the same as `lua_State`s.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Lua so I may sound little dumb. But we are running this from a Lua file, I think `lua_state` is the one we create when we are executing from a C file and not a Lua file.Can you point me to any example where we can create new `lua_state` from a Lua file. And thanks for your earlier reply :).

Comment: The `lua_State` is what actually runs the Lua code; the `luajit` executable is simply a frontend for it. The only way to create a `lua_State` is from Lua's C API, which you can access via the FFI, but that's beyond the scope of this question.